# How to convert String to PWideChar in Android Platform using Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

how to convert string to PwideChar in Android Platform using Delphi ? in windows apps its done using..

```
var    
  PW: PWideChar;
begin
  PW := pwidechar(widestring(String));
  PW := pwidechar(widestring(Reply));
  A := ExistWordInString(PW,String,[soWholeWord,soDown]); //A : Boolean

....
end;
```

the problems is `Undeclared identifier: 'WideString'` , how to work around this ?

Delphi 10 Berlin , Firemonkey, Android

**UPDATE**

well, according to http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop ,, we cant use widestring, i cant think of another way to use string this function :

```
function ExistWordInString(aString:PWideChar;aSearchString:string;aSearchOptions: TStringSearchOptions): Boolean;
var
  Size : Integer;
Begin
  Size:=StrLen(aString);
  Result := SearchBuf(aString, Size, 0, 0, aSearchString, aSearchOptions)<>nil;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is not strictly correct in Windows. Yes you can convert `string` (an alias for `UnicodeString`) to the COM `WideString`, but this is a waste of time and resources. The correct code is:

```
var    
  P: PWideChar;
  S: string;
....
P := PWideChar(S);
```

In fact, since you are using a Unicode version of Delphi, it is probably idiomatic to use `PChar` (an alias for `PWideChar`), to fit alongside `string`.

So I would write:

```
var    
  P: PChar;
  S: string;
....
P := PChar(S);
```

Now, this code, as well as being the correct way to do this on Windows, works equally on all platforms.